# C File Manipulation via shell execution of "cat"

Tags: c

[edit] - The answer, as described by the responses below, is I should have used fclose instead of close.

The C library's `system()` function is behaving unexpectedly for me.  A toy example of the error is below.

I have a data file "file_2.txt" with three lines of data

```
file 2 line 1
file 2 line 2
file 2 line 3
```

The following C program appends this data to file_1.txt, a file built within the program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE *fname = fopen("file_1.txt","w");

    fprintf(fname,"file 1 line 1\n");
    fprintf(fname,"file 1 line 2\n");
    fprintf(fname,"file 1 line 3\n");
    fprintf(fname,"file 1 line 4\n");
    fprintf(fname,"file 1 line 5\n");

    close(fname);

    system("cat file_2.txt >> file_1.txt");
    system("cat file_1.txt");
}
```

I expect the output to be

```
file 1 line 1
file 1 line 2
file 1 line 3
file 1 line 4
file 1 line 5
file 2 line 1
file 2 line 2
file 2 line 3
```

but instead I just get

```
file 2 line 1
file 2 line 2
file 2 line 3
```

What has happened to the lines of file_1.txt?

Comment: If you use `fopen` you should also use `fclose`.  See the manual page to understand the differences between fopen/fclose and open/close.

Comment: A call to C standard library's [`system(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) is *not* a ["system call"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call).

Comment: Your compiler probably gave you a warningl mine did: `a.c:14:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'close' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    close(fname);` Don't ignore the warnings!  They will often tip you off to where the problem is.

Comment: Unfortunately my compiler gave no warning.  I am using gcc "out of the box" (gcc version 4.6.3).

Comment: Learn to use the options that would make GCC warn you.  At minimum, use `-Wall`.  I normally use `gcc -g -O3 -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror`, which certainly wouldn't have let your code compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `fclose(fname)` instead of `close(fname)`. The `close()` function expects a *file descriptor*, which is an integer not a `FILE *`. The `fclose()` function is what you need to use to close a file opened with `fopen()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

It was indeed because I was using close as opposed to fclose.

Answer (score 2):

`fprintf()` is a *libC* function that puts a buffering layer in front of the system call `write()`. When you add data using `fprintf()` it may be stored in a userspace buffer, until there is enough data so it is worth making a system call. By calling the `close()` system call you closed the file at the OS level and the *libC* didn't get a chance to flush any outstanding data in the buffer associated with your file.

**EDIT**: Moreover, `fclose()` takes a FILE pointer as argument whereas `close()` expects a file handle number, so in your program `close()` actually tried to close garbage and then the program ended without giving libC a chance to write awaiting data.

Comment: Passing a `FILE*` to `close()` will cause the kernel to try to close some random file descriptor that doesn't correspond to an actual file, and effectively do nothing. So the file never closed at all. (Of course, also the file buffer was not flushed.)

Comment: You're right, I edited my post to tell the whole truth.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  using fclose fixed the problem.

Comment: The standard term for what you called 'file handle number' is 'file descriptor'.  A very common name for the variable is `int fd = open(…);`, comparable to `FILE *fp = fopen(…);`.